# Firebase getSignedUrl inside loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I need to get urls of all files in 'bucket/loads/:loadID' path. I'm able to get these files in array called 'files'. Then I filter it (I get endFiles array). And now I just need a new array called url to push all the urls in (getSignedUrl). But I don't know how to do It. I need to get signed urls inside a loop (endFiles.forEach) and push it to urls array or something like that.

```
exports.testCloudFunc = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async object => {
  const filePath = object.name;

  const { Logging } = require('@google-cloud/logging');
  console.log(`Logged: FILEPATH: ${filePath}`);
  const id = filePath.split('/');
  console.log(`Logged: ID: ${id[0]}/${id[1]}`);
  const bucket = object.bucket;
  console.log(`Logged: BUCKET: ${object.bucket}`);

  async function listFilesByPrefix() {
    const options = {
      prefix: id[0] + '/' + id[1]
    };
    const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucket).getFiles(options);

    const endFiles = files.filter(el => {
      return (
        el.name === id[0] + '/' + id[1] + '/' + 'invoiceReport.pdf' ||
        el.name === id[0] + '/' + id[1] + '/' + 'POD.pdf' ||
        el.name === id[0] + '/' + id[1] + '/' + 'rateConfirmation.pdf'
      );
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < endFiles.length; i++) {
      console.log(endFiles[i].name);
    }
  }
  listFilesByPrefix().catch(console.error);
});
```

I'm stuck and need help. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`getSignedUrl()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#getSignedUrl) method is asynchronous and returns a Promise.

Since you want to concurrently execute multiple calls to this method, you need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows:

```
  async function listFilesByPrefix() {
    const options = {
      prefix: id[0] + '/' + id[1]
    };
    const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucket).getFiles(options);

    const endFiles = files.filter(el => {
      return (
        el.name === id[0] + '/' + id[1] + '/' + 'invoiceReport.pdf' ||
        el.name === id[0] + '/' + id[1] + '/' + 'POD.pdf' ||
        el.name === id[0] + '/' + id[1] + '/' + 'rateConfirmation.pdf'
      );
    });

    const config = {
       action: 'read',
       expires: '03-17-2025'
    };

    const promises = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < endFiles.length; i++) {
      console.log(endFiles[i].name);
      promises.push(endFiles[i].getSignedUrl(config));
    }

    const urlsArray = await Promise.all(promises);  

    return urlsArray;
  }


  listFilesByPrefix()
  .then(results => {
     //results is an array of signed URLs
     //It's worth noting that values in the array will be in order of the Promises passed with promises.push()
     //do whatever you need, for example:
     results.forEach(url => {
         //....
     });
   })
```

Comment: I'm getting this 
`Error: Permission iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob is required to perform this operation on service account projects/alex-logistics/serviceAccounts/alex-logistics@appspot.gserviceaccount.com.`

Comment: I have enabled service account token creator and service account storage object creator in roles in google console. Now it's working as it should! Thank you a lot!